# How to copy two commit ID inside git log?

Tags: git, bash, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

**Situation:**

I am using **zsh** (oh-my-zsh). When I was using **Bash** I was able to scroll the `git log` so that I can copy and paste the commit IDs for other operations.

It is probably that there are so many commit for this repository. Now whenever I use `git log` in **zsh**, it seems jump to another window so I can only past one commit ID at a time and I cannot enter any command inside that window, except `q`.

What I am currently doing is to copy the commit IDs to textpad and prepare for later usage.

**Question:**

Is there a way I can make the git log show all histroy in the same window as other command? Just like in **Bash**. OR Is there a way I can copy two commit ID at onece?

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make `git log` command non interactive use:

```
git --no-pager log
```

or, pipe it to cat like:

```
git log | cat
```

You can also use -N, which limits the output to only the last N entries:

(in this example last 2 entries)

```
git --no-pager log -2
```

To search the commit log for the given text you can use git's built in grep command like:

```
git --no-pager log --grep='My commit msg'
```

Comment: `git log | cat` seems lost all git color ouput. `git --no-pager log` seems work just fine. But when there are really large number of commits how do you find the desired one? Thank you. :D

Comment: There is built in grep command, please check updated version of answer.

Comment: Thanks. Remind me that I just read about `grep` this morning.

Comment: `--grep="..."` is case-sensitive is there non-casesensitive method?

Comment: Yup, it's `-i` flag, like `git --no-pager log -i --grep='My commit msg'`

Comment: When I read `man git` I cannot find flags like `-i` and `--grep`. Seems all of them are from **Unix**. How did you find thses information? Thank you.

Comment: From `man git` i have found `git-log(1)` entry, and when you check that `man git-log` you can find all `git log` docs.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found everthing you mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A different solution that works in some shells, and should work in yours (since I am also using oh-my-zsh):

1. Enter the `git log` pager and copy your first Commit ID
2. Copy it, leave the pager (<kbd>q</kbd>)
3. Start typing your git command, paste the ID, e.g

   ```
   git diff f6a8d92c
   ```
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to 'suspend' the typed-but-not-sent command on the terminal. It will go away and you can run a different command.
5. Run `git log` to enter the log again, copy the other ID, leave it with <kbd>q</kbd>.
6. Now, the previously suspended command should be at your prompt again (it appears always after the next finished command, which was `git log`). You can suspend it again if you want by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>.
7. Paste the second ID to create the full command.

Hope you can follow the steps, if not, please tell me where it fails. If the suspend shortcut does not work, maybe it's because your shell has it somewhere else or does not support it. The feature is apparently called "push-line".

Comment: `Ctrl + q` does not work on my terminal. I am using **iTerm 2** (Build 2.0.0.20141103) and **zsh** 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)